# asp.net multiplied database notifications

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

there is asp.net (webforms) app, that shows database change notifications, source code: [here](http://ruchirac.blogspot.com/2014/10/get-database-change-notification-in.html)

When multiple clients connect, or even one hits refresh (F5), the notification is send multiple times (multiplied by number of refresh, or connected clients).

Any help?

Comment: Can't see the question for which you want help. Please clarify

Comment: When someone updates database record, there should be a notification on the client machine (in web browser). It's working ok, but when another client run's the app, or only one client runs app and hit refresh, the notification after update is still comming, but multiplied by number of clients or refreshes (multiplied on every client). So for example, when 3 clients are runnning app, everyone is getting 3 same notifications for one update. Everyone should get only one notification for one update.

Comment: I guess if you receive multiple times the notification, it's because you subscribed multiple times to the "OnChange" event. You should add a trace where you subscribe and unsuscribe the event.